# How to set vertical angle of spherebuffergeometry? Why Orbit controls don't work properly when mesh is rotated?

Tags: javascript, three.js, panoramas

I am having issues trying to set the default view of a panoramic image inside spherebuffergeometry. I have a mesh that makes use of this geometry and the material is an equirectangle panorama image. During runtime, the default view of the image is somewhere towards the right. I want the initial angle to be at the bottom of the camera. I tried changing the Phi angle and theta angle parameters of spherebuffergeometry. While I am able to move the default horizontal angle by changing Phi angle, the panoramic image looks weird when I change the theta angle.

I took the first two snapshots when phi angle was 0 and 100 respectively and theta angle was 0. I took the last snapshot when phi angle was 100 and theta angle was 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
 sphereBufferGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100,100,100,0,Math.PI*2,0,Math.PI);            sphereBufferGeometry.scale( 1, 1, -1 );  
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                                    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load([image] )
                                });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereBufferGeometry, material );
```

[image: Phi angle]
[image: Phi angle=120]

[image: Theta angle=1]

I have tried this as well.

```js
init();
var scene,renderer,camera;

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
  
    var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffddcc, 1 );
    light.position.set( 1, 0.75, 0.5 );
    scene.add( light2 );
  var sphereBufferGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI);
  sphereBufferGeometry.scale(1, 1, -1);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/2294472375_24a3b8ef46_o.jpg')
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereBufferGeometry, material);
  mesh.rotation.x=1.6;
  scene.add(camera);
  scene.add(light);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  var orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 0.001);
  orbitControls.update();

  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  canvas.setAttribute("class", "frame");
  container.appendChild(canvas);
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  animate();
}

function animate()
{
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/105/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

. As you can see, I've rotated the mesh so that the default view is looking at the floor.. if we click and drag the mouse upwards such that the window in the view is horizontal and then click and drag left or right, orbit controls don't seem to work properly in that it doesn't give a proper panoramic experience.. I would like to know how can this be fixed

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. If you just want to start looking down then aim the camera down.

Comment: Basically, I want the default view to focus the bottom part of the image without changing the camera angle.

Comment: Then you'd probably have to rotate the sphere. The texture itself will only work with a full sphere and no changes in UVs (well you can probably move U but not V)

Comment: I tried rotating the sphere but the orbitcontrols don't seem to work properly afterwards

Comment: Post a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. If you use a snippet then this requirement is covered. Because you used jsfiddle instead and the code required to repo the problem is not in the question itself your question is off topic of stackoverflow. Is there some reason you didn't use a snippet?

Comment: I can't find the icon to click on to add a snippet.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Di3vCMK

Comment: thanks @gman I've updated the original post

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't think you can do what you are trying to do with the OrbitControls. They appear to be hard coded to rotate around a north-south pole. You could try the TrackballControls as they don't seem to have that limit. But, since they don't have that limit they also don't remember which way is up. Otherwise I think you're going to have to write your own or modify one of those.